# how to animate/spin actor around it's center point?

Tags: gnome, vala, clutter

i'm using Clutter and Vala to animate different stuff. But when I for example rotate an actor around the z-axis, it dosen't just spin around itself. Instead it spins around the top-left cornor as if it was the center point. I think it has something to do with a bindcontraint but couldn't find much information about it.

so my question is: how can I make the actor spin around the center point of itself?

any examples is appreciated :) thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to use the `Clutter.Actor.pivot_point` property, which describes the reference point for all transformations (rotation, scaling, translation).

it's important to note that the `pivot_point` property is expressed in a normalized coordinate space, relative to the size of the actor itself. so:

```
actor.pivot_point = Clutter.Point() { x = 0.0, y = 0.0 };
```

is the top-left corner of the actor;

```
actor.pivot_point = Clutter.Point() { x = 1.0, y = 1.0 };
```

is the bottom-right corner of the actor; and

```
actor.pivot_point = Clutter.Point() { x = 0.5, y = 0.5 };
```

is the center of the actor — regardless of the values in the `Clutter.Actor.width` and `Clutter.Actor.height` properties of the actor.

more information is available in the API reference: https://developer.gnome.org/clutter/stable/ClutterActor.html#ClutterActor--pivot-point

Comment: this was exactly what i asked for. Had to modify the code but it's basically the same:
`public Clutter.Point center ()
 {
  Clutter.Point a;
  a = Clutter.Point.alloc();
  
  a.init(0.5f, 0.5f);
  
  return a;
 }`